# "combine this with previous var . . ." statement

Tags: javascript, jslint

Other answers on this site regarding my question haven't helped. Hoping to get another view.

I have received this message: "combine this with previous var statement.  var changeText = paragraph[1].style.fontStyle = "italic";"

I am following a tutorial on YouTube and my code matches up with the guy's code on the video. I have had to add "user strict"; because I was instructed by JSLint. But everything else is the same.

Why is this code not working?

Here is my HTML:

```js
function changeStyle() {
    "use strict";
    var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var changeText = paragraph[1].style.fontStyle = "italic";
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>JS Tutorials-2</title>
    <meta name="js tutorials-2" content="js tutorials-2">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js-tutorials-2.css">

</head>
<body>


    <header>
        <div class="banner"><h1 id="head">Javascript</h1></div>
        <div class="banner2"><h1 id ="another-head">The Adventure Begins</h1></div>
    </header>


            <p id = "para2">Text Goes Here </p>
            <p id = "para3">Text Goes Here</p>
            <p id = "para4">Text Goes Here </p>
            <p id = "para5">Text Goes Here</p>

            <button onclick = "changeStyle()">Submit</button>


</body>
```

Comment: It's just a JSLint warning. It has nothing to do with the actual execution of the code. See for example: http://linterrors.com/js/combine-this-with-the-previous-var-statement

Comment: From that link: "The fact that JSLint does not allow you to simply have multiple variable statements outside of the block is just the coding convention preferred by the author, Douglas Crockford." - I for one disagree with that coding convention, and prefer multiple `var` groups for related variables. For instances, I might have `var grid = [...]; var x, y;`... At the end of the day, coding conventions are simply a matter of opinion, they're more like guidelines than actual rules.

Comment: What @NiettheDarkAbsol said - by all means read Crockford and understand *why* he uses certain conventions and then decided for yourself if you agree or not. Don't just blindly apply them without know what they are and why they exist.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the suggestion is to have just one `var` declaration for both `paragraph` and `changeText`:

```
var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName("p"),
    changeText = paragraph[1].style.fontStyle = "italic";
```

Now, in addition to that, it's not really clear what you're doing with that `changeText` variable anyway; its value will always be the string "italic". If your function really does contain only those two lines, then what you *really* want is probably:

```
var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
paragraph[1].style.fontStyle = "italic";
```

Comment: Even though I'm new to this I can see what you're saying about not needing the extra var. Though, this was how it was done on the tutorial and it worked. I have taken your suggestion, but the code still doesn't italicise the targeted item (paragraph[1].

Comment: @jwdwsn Note that the first paragraph in the list is `paragraph[0]`, not `paragraph[1]`. Indexes start at zero.

Comment: I'm trying to italicise the second index, therefore the [1]. Again, I'm not sure why one person can have a particular code that works and myself have the same code but it not work. It seems like I'm missing something really obvious here, but since I'm relatively new, I'm missing it.

Comment: @jwdwsn if you run the snippet right here in your question, you'll see that it is italicizing the second paragraph when the button is clicked.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I'm using Brackets editor and it is not italicising anything. I'm guessing then, it has something to do with the editor. I'll look into it. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Turns out it was the editor I was using. I switched from Brackets to Sublime Text and the same code works perfect.